# How do I extract lists to excel?

Tags: apache, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I apologize if this is a stupid question.But why can I only extract one list to an excel?  I've tried modifying it but I don't really understand why I can't have 2 columns side by side with the extracted data.  Instead it displays one.

Any fixes?

I have following code :

```
public class dads 
{ 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
        SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("output");
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("czPA LEASE.xlsx",true);

        // DRIVER
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Death_Note_episodes");

        List<WebElement> Elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tbody//td//i"));
        int x=-1;
        int y=1;
        for(WebElement ele: Elements)
        {
            System.out.println(ele.getText());
            SXSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow((short)++x);
            SXSSFCell cell=dataRow.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
        }

        List<WebElement> Elements1=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tbody//td"));

        int x1=-1;
        int y1=2;
        for(WebElement ele1: Elements1)
        {
            System.out.println(ele1.getText());
            SXSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow((short)++x1);
            SXSSFCell cell1=dataRow.createCell(1);
            cell1.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell1.setCellValue(ele1.getText());
        }

        try 
        {
            f.flush();
            workbook.write(f);
            f.close();
            System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
            driver.close();

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a limitation of the code or I just need to read the entirety of apache documentation and go through apache stuff in general...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you to find you answer:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
public class Test {

    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    static WebElement element ;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        String excelFileName = "C:/Test.xls";//name of excel file

        String sheetName = "Sheet1";//name of sheet

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName) ;
        // DRIVER
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Death_Note_episodes");

        List<WebElement> rows=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@class='wikitable'][1]//th[contains(@id,'ep')]"));
        //iterating r number of rows
        for (int r=0;r < rows.size(); r++ )
        {
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);
            List<WebElement> cloumns = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@class='wikitable'][1]//th[@id='ep"+r+"']//parent::tr[1]/td"));
            //iterating c number of columns
            for (int c=0;c < cloumns.size(); c++ )
            {
                HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);

                cell.setCellValue(cloumns.get(c).getText());
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);

        //write this workbook to an Outputstream.
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  For me that opens Firefox (twice) and then it just freezes at the url webpage and doesn't extract the attributes after that.  I wonder why that is it doesn't give an error just freezes

Comment: Sorry I spoke to soon.  That works 100%.  You're a legend!  Why are there three columns for 2 data sets though o.o

Comment: Hmm is there any way to adjust that so the data on the second column just keeps going down rather than creating a third column?  Would get messy with lots of data.  Hopefully I can find that out

Comment: What do you mean by 2 data set here? What i have tried is, i got the no.of rows & columns.And created file with column values.

Comment: For me it seems to get Column one gets the data exactly as it is on the webpage.  But Column two gets the data until it equals columns 1 and then it creates a new column.  I can attach an image if I am not explaining well enough :S

Comment: So my question I'm trying to work out is how do  I modify that code to make it so that instead of creating a new column it just lets the data continue in the column 2 :)

Comment: Those are questions I'll have to ponder on I guess.  Not too sure how to resolve but will keep researching.  Thanks for your help :D.  I don't think this would work for any data not a table.  But works well for a table if it has even rows